# AngularJS app initializes but doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have started a pet project with AngularJS and Gulp. The code is available on [github](https://github.com/ptrvtch/fincontrol).

After building the project my `dist` folder looks like this:

```
js/
--vendor.js
--app.js
index.html
```

When I run browserSync in `dist` folder, everything seems to work fine: the paths are injected correctly, `angular` global variable is available in chrome console, and ng-app directive is on its place. However, if I try to create a controller or config an app, the scripts inside the functions don't run.

That's the first time when I actually wrote `gulpfile.js` entirely by myself, based on various tutorials. I suspect that the problem may be in improper gulp configuration, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is app working without gulp?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav it needs gulp to inject script paths to index.html. You can't run local server in src folder.

Comment: I am not sure it is good idea to build your application this way. What for you want to use gulp? For building your application (like packing all files into one or more bundles etc). In my opinion, it is strange that you can't run your application both on sources and on buillded code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in index.html change **ng-app** to **ng-app="app"** add browser-sync in dependencies. other than that everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to specify module name in ngApp directive. This will fix problem that `config` and `run` blocks are not running.
Also you have to add ngController directive somewhere. For example on `body` html tag.

Result: [image]

Example of final html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>FinControl</title>
  <!-- build:css css/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- build:css css/main.css -->
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
</head>

<body ng-controller="testCtrl" layout="column" layout-fill>
  <input type="text" ng-model="textVal">
  <span>{{textval}}</span>
</body>
  <!-- build:js js/vendor.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- build:js js/app.js -->
  <!-- inject:js -->
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- endbuild -->

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to explicitly name the app as well as specify the controller, but probably not both at the same time.